# Basic commutative algebra from a more advanced viewpoint: reference request

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory

I am studying a course in commutative algebra, basically the contents of Aitiyah-MacDonald, so a very standard syllabus.

Actually what I find most fascinating is the "universal" viewpoint on the algebraic structure I meet, such as rings, ideals, modules, algebras, rather than studying their particular properties. Thus most references I find quite unsatisfactory, since they mention at most some universal properties of these structures and study them almost only from an "arithmetical" viewpoint. On the other hand, references using category theory or the approach based on congruences and algebraic structures are usually on higher problems and do not cover such a syllabus. Moreover these two approaches are often exclusive.

My background in the field is basic category and model theory, basic algebra.
I would be curious if some midway exists: basic fundamental syllabus, but adopting a more categorical "universal" viewpoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aluffis Algebra: Chapter 0 should fit the bill

Comment: This question could be useful : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716878/categorical-introduction-to-algebra-and-topology?rq=1